# how to do a php and Mysql Standalone deployment package

Tags: php, mysql, flash

im not new to PHP and Mysql, but i have working on it in Web apps for the past few years,
I am starting a new project, and it has the following:
1.the project itself will be built on Adobe Air (Flash) environments //as per clients's request
2.there is going to be a custom dictionary (in php), tht is linked to the Flash program su ch tht when a user clicks the word in flash the dictionary should open and land on the word means etc..
 My question now is how do i link the two.. ie to pass the Variable from flash to php dictionary if its standalone & how do i make the installation package for Mysql standalone?

Please any assistance will be appreciated.

PHP_GURU

Comment: If you are asking how to install the separate packages on a server, serverfault.com would be a better place to ask.  As it stands, I can't quiet make out what you are asking.

Comment: Why does it need to be stand-alone? Why don't you just install php and mysql on a central webserver and access that? Your suggested approach sort of defeats the whole purpose of using php+mysql.

Comment: @Wouter van Nifterick when he says standalone, i believe he is talking about the flash client not being imbedded in a webpage, and instead being run as a standalone application...?

Comment: Is it a requirement that this should all work without an available internet connection?

Answer (score 0):

use the URLLoader and URLRequest classes to send a message from Flash to a PHP script. can be used to send POST data as well.

http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/net/URLLoader.html

Comment: Okay the problem is that,this is more like a software project for kids(learning stuff) and the company im working for want this to be on every pc ( as a stand alone), if they happen to change their minds on tht ill be set, bcz i knw how to do it as a web app, but until then im stuck plz guys- im getting desperate here PHP_GURU

Comment: the reason why it has to be a standalone is tht the final users do not have access to internet, and they are basically independent machines

Comment: @PHP_GURU if they do not have access to the internet, then the solution is to not use php or mysql for your project at all. if they did have the internet, you could build standalone exe flash applications that connect to the internet and use php and mysql. they have computers that don't have internet? really?